# Maintaining working precision in my program

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, number-representation, numerical-value

I am badly stuck with this program I am writing. I want output of program below to be precise up to 25 digits after decimal point. I am supplying all inputs with precision 25.
But after each iteration of main for loop, precision keeps on decreasing by some points. And as a result in about 100 iterations precision comes down to 0.
I tried everything that I can think of including explicitly setting precision using `SetPrecision` in `f1,f2,f3,N1,N2,N3,a`. That would produce output but it's not correct as `SetPrecision` is just padding the digits from right.
Appreciate any help/suggestions. Thankx.

Input:

```
Clear["Global`*"]; order = 0.89`25; parameter = 27.3`25; ic = {1000000001/100000000`25., 
  10, 10}; SIZE = 100;
```

Program:

```
   AbsoluteTiming[alph = bet = gam = order; h = 2/100; omeg = -2667/1000;
  mu = 10; A = parameter; B = 1;
 Array[y1, SIZE, 0]; y1[0] = ic[[1]];
 Array[y2, SIZE, 0]; y2[0] = ic[[2]]; Array[y3, SIZE, 0]; 
 y3[0] = ic[[3]];
 a[0 _, k_] := (k - 1)^(alph + 1) - (k - 1 - alph) k^alph;
 a[j_, k_] := (k - j + 1)^(alph + 1) + (k - 1 - j)^(alph + 1) - 
    2 (k - j)^(alph + 1) /; (1 <= j <= k - 1);
 a[j_, k_] := 1 /; j == k;
 l1 := h^alph/Gamma[alph + 2]; l2 := h^bet/Gamma[bet + 2]; 
 l3 := h^gam/Gamma[gam + 2];
 f1[t_, n_] := 
  l1*Sum[a[j, n]*omeg*y1[j], {j, 0, n - 1}] - 
   l1*Sum[a[j, n]*y2[j]*y2[j], {j, 0, n - 1}];
 f2[t_, n_] := 
  mu + l2*Sum[a[j, n]*mu*y3[j], {j, 0, n - 1}] - 
   l2*Sum[a[j, n]*mu*y2[j], {j, 0, n - 1}];
 f3[t_, n_] := 
  mu + l3*Sum[a[j, n]*A*y2[j], {j, 0, n - 1}] - 
   l3*Sum[a[j, n]*B*y3[j], {j, 0, n - 1}] + 
   l3*Sum[a[j, n]*y1[j]*y2[j], {j, 0, n - 1}];
 N1[u1_, u2_, u3_] := l1*(omeg*u1 - u2*u2);
 N2[u1_, u2_, u3_] := l2*(mu*u3 - mu*u2);
 N3[u1_, u2_, u3_] := l3*(A*u2 - B*u3 + u1*u2);
 For[i = 1, i <= SIZE - 1, i++,   (*main loop*)
  y10 = f1[h*i, i];
  y20 = f2[h*i, i];
  y30 = f3[h*i, i];
  y11 = N1[y10, y20, y30];
  y21 = N2[y10, y20, y30];
  y31 = N3[y10, y20, y30];
  y12 = N1[y10 + y11, y20 + y21, y30 + y31] - N1[y10, y20, y30];
  y22 = N2[y10 + y11, y20 + y21, y30 + y31] - N2[y10, y20, y30];
  y32 = N3[y10 + y11, y20 + y21, y30 + y31] - N3[y10, y20, y30];
  y1[i] = y10 + y11 + y12;
  y2[i] = y20 + y21 + y22;
  y3[i] = y30 + y31 + y32;];
 xx = Table[y1[i], {i, 0, SIZE - 1}];
 yy = Table[y2[i], {i, 0, SIZE - 1}];
 zz = Table[y3[i], {i, 0, SIZE - 1}];
]
```

Output error: `General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation. >>` Further it tells me *there are no significant digits remaining to display.*

```
Output:
In[78]:= xx

Out[78]= {1.000000000000000000000000, -3.35160956937173040383529, \
-7.6063107290506868684570, -13.965998348176594403068, \
-23.217734641185881084877, -34.75517400137475702813, \
-45.6273435387493774249, -52.0072035922437294633, \
-52.794258502857519941, -49.988719962104854383, \
-45.92876611511978598, -41.92397139618361145, -38.44386042357929135, \
-35.5347038434195767, -33.090746410617466, -30.988018715710107, \
-29.13155464170869, -27.46064718989206, -25.9403613009447, \
-24.5520756248237, -23.286816115939, -22.14149256760, \
-21.11722129330, -20.2189730943, -19.4560502901, -18.843109037, \
-18.401537933, -18.16095921, -18.16039845, -18.4482145, -19.0791605, \
-20.106105, -21.563607, -23.44219, -25.65784, -28.0311, -30.298, \
-32.166, -33.40, -33.90, -33.7, -32.9, -32., -30., -3.*10^1, \
-3.*10^1, -0.*10^1, 0.*10^2, 0.*10^3, 0.*10^7, 0.*10^19, 0.*10^63, 
 0.*10^219, 0.*10^766, 0.*10^2695, 0.*10^9485, 0.*10^33394, 
 0.*10^117589, 0.*10^414071, 0.*10^1458094, 0.*10^5134494, 
 0.*10^18080495, 0.*10^63668287, 0.*10^224200219, Overflow[], 
 Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], 
 Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], 
 Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], 
 Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], 
 Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], 
 Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], 
 Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[]}
```

Precision:

```
In[79]:= Precision[xx]

Out[79]= 0.
```

Program works fine with `MachinePrecision` but that is not output I want.

Comment: Did you try to set the `$MinPrecission` to desired value? Like `$MinPrecission=25` ??

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: @Rom38 wow. It worked like charm. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can reset precision or set a min precision, but unless there is an independent error analysis the result might be garbage.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I understand your point. Could you guide me where to look up for error analysis  for this type of programs?

Comment: This is not information I have at my fingertips. I guess it falls into the general area of automatic differentiation. You want some gauge of precision change and a linearized estimate might be found by partial derivatives. One way to approximate might be to do computations in fixed precision with small changes in inputs, then use differences to estimate partial derivatives.